# « (Être) sur la brosse » au Québec ?

Tags: québec, argot, origine-ou-raison

Pourquoi, au Québec, on dit « sur la brosse » en parlant de l'alcool ? Par ex. [Chu Ben Plus Cool Su'a Brosse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZGppyWlM38%22) (vidéo).

Comment: C'est **sur** et non "sous" la brosse. *Être sur la brosse* signifie en effet, comme le remarque (indirectement) Gardenal, "être soul".

Comment: merci, c'est corrigé

Answer (score 1):

Ça doit être la même expression que **virer une brosse**

Il me semble que **broisse** en ancien français désigne les broussailles et autres buissons et était utilisé pour dire partir à l'aventure, vadrouiller, même s'il est peu en usage aujourd'hui **brosser** signifie toujours "partir à la chasse" (dans les bois donc).

Donc j'ignore si le Québec a une histoire particulière qui lierait la chasse et l'alcool, mais il pourrait y avoir un lien de ce genre, à moins que ce ne soit simplement l'idée d'aller faire un peu n'importe quoi (comme par exemple boire outre mesure...)

Answer (score 1):

On trouve au TLFi à [*brosse*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brosse) « 3. Arg. *Prendre une brosse.* S'enivrer. *Être en brosse.* Être ivre. *Une brosse* (cf. se brosser). Rien[.] ». Je suis originaire du Québec : le premier tour est identique au tour québécois pour le sens figuré de *s'enivrer*, que le DHLF/Rey qualifie de propre au Québec ; je trouve le deuxième entièrement inusité, je dis plutôt *être sur la brosse*, *avoir pris/viré une brosse*, ou *être en boisson* (rare) ; l'emploi pour *rien* m'est inconnu. Dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/28065) on a traité de l'[étymologie](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/42677) "de l’ancien français *broisse* « taillis, broussaille, menu bois, broutille », dont le sens s’est conservé dans le verbe *brosser*, en langage de chasse : « courir à travers des bois épais »" (Wiktionnaire, à [*brosse*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brosse)). Voici quelques pistes de réflexions supplémentaires...

---

*Pourquoi la brosse ?*

Dans un article d'il y a plus de 50 ans, « [Five Canadian-French Etymologies: barrabasser, brosse, Jean- Baptiste Beaufouet, piasse, pichou.](https://books.google.com/books?id=zgYrAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22five%20Canadian-French%20etymologies%20%3A%20BARRABASSER%2C%20BROSSE%2C%20JEAN-BAPTISTE%20BEAUFOUET%2C%20PIASSE%2C%20PICHOU%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=cup) » Romance Philology, Vol. 14 (1961), G.J. Brault (dont la conclusion nous est inaccessible), on mentionne à tout le moins l'entrée au GPFC, la *broisse* en ancien français et la variante *breusse* de Rabelais... donc une référence à une ***coupe/tasse*** pour boire du vin et aux contextes associés : « Lors flaccons d’aller, jambons de troter, goubeletz de voler, breusses de tinter. » (Rabelais au [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/breusse), par ex. [BnF](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5806585m/f33.image.r=breusses), [Wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Gargantua)). Voici extrait du contenu au GPFC :

[image]
<sup><sup>[*Glossaire du parler français au Canada*](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf), Société du parler français au Canada, Geoffrion/Rivard, 1930, (montage).</sup></sup>

Avec le substantif (*brosse*), l'ancien français *broisse* dont il est question ici [serait peut-être](https://books.google.com/books?id=oZ5srdbQngEC&lpg=PA132&dq=breusse%20rabelais%20angevin%20duchat&pg=PA132#v=onepage&q=breusse&f=false) une forme angevine attestée antérieurement... ce serait dérivé de l'etymon [*bròchis*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/10/549) (voir [*broc*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/broc)) et non de [*bruschia*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/42677) (*Etymologisches Wörterbuch zu Rabelais (Gargantua)*, Baldinger). Avec le verbe on aurait peut-être un apport différent par le truchement de certains [termes](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/42677) reliés à l'étymon *bruschia*. Je suis moins familier avec l'emploi de *brosser* qu'avec les locutions avec *brosse*.

Incidemment, c'est peut-être aussi relié à une variante orthographique de *broche* ([*broccus*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/42349)) dans son sens de la « cheville pour boucher le trou qu'on fait au tonneau avec le foret » ([Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/next/complement-godefroy/380/8/broche)), qui s'emploie dans *vendre à broche* soit « vendre (le vin) en le tirant au fur et à mesure, le vendre au détail »([DmF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/broche1?idf=dmfXhgYrmXart.revusYboXbbd;str=0)).

---

*Pourquoi la préposition (être) sur (la brosse) ?*

Le GPFC donne *partir sur une brosse* comme équivalent d'*être en train de prendre un cuite*. *Être sur* c'est simplement *prendre/avoir pris*, à mon avis ; c'est bien courant à l'oral au Québec (*être sur les pilules*, ...*le LSD* ; mais pas *être sur le pot* (x), plutôt *avoir fumé du pot*, ...*consommé de la marijuana* etc.). L'emploi de la préposition *sur* dans ce genre de contexte est peut-être influencé par celle de *on* en langue anglaise, que [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_s&page=96YCcur_pUEE.html) corrige : *sur la drogue (être)*, *on drugs (to be)*, prendre de la drogue ; voir aussi [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2484)...

---

Le lexique reste touffu, on n'a pas l'expertise, et on ne sait pas si on a tranché ailleurs, mais au final cette *breusse* à Rabelais sous influence avec l'auxiliaire (*être su'(r l)a brosse*) pourrait faire référence au fait d'« avoir pris un verre (de vin !) », au propre. Imaginez...